# If $R = \frac{P}{Q}$ is a rational function, does $f(R) := \deg (P) - \deg (Q)$ have a traditional name/notation?

Tags: terminology, rational-functions

Suppose $R : C \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a (univariate) rational function. Write $R=P/Q,$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomial functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

1. Is there a traditional name/notation for the number $f(R)=\deg(P)-\deg(Q)$? ([According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function#Complex_rational_functions), the phrase "degree of $R$" is usually understood to mean $\max\{\deg(P), \deg(Q)\}.$)
2. Is there existing terminology to distinguish the cases where $f(R)>0$, $f(R)=0$, and $f(R)<0$? These correspond to different behaviours in the limit as we approach infinity.

Comment: well one can use $R \sim_\infty x^a$, and of course $a = \deg(P) - \deg(Q)$

Comment: In this context you could call it $\deg R$. Yes, in other situations the degree of a rational function is defined differently, but this expression is also called the degree of $R$.

Comment: "this expression is also called the degree of $R$" is that really true @KCd? A link or reference would be nice.

Comment: Yes, it is really true. Let's see if that comment or this one get up votes as "proof." In valuation theory, if $F$ is a field then every valuation on $F(x)$ that is trivial on $F$ and has value group $\mathbf Z$ is nonnegative on $F[x]$ except for the valuation at infinity ${\rm ord}_\infty(g) = -\deg g$. This is the extension of the degree from nonzero polynomials to nonzero rational functions defined as in your question. Then $\deg g > 0$ means $g$ has a pole "at infinity," $\deg g < 0$ means $g$ has a zero at infinity, and $\deg g = 0$ means $g$ is a unit at infinity.

Comment: I meant in my previous comment that ${\rm ord}_\infty$ is the extension of the *negative degree* from polynomials to rational functions: ${\rm ord}_\infty(P/Q) = \deg Q-\deg P = -\deg(P/Q)$ for polynomials $P$ and $Q$ in $F[x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 18th of November, 2014, KCd said:

> In this context you could call it $\deg(R)$. Yes, in other situations
>   the degree of a rational function is defined differently, but this
>   expression is also called the degree of $R$.